# French accents dont working with Twilio SMS

Tags: sms, twilio, non-ascii-characters, french

I want to send sms message for group of numbers, without going through with coding a script, is there any solution in twilio console that can help me with that?

Those characters do not show and replaced with a space: é,à .... Does anyone know a trick or something?

Comment: How have you sent those messages with the errors so far? What have you used to send the messages?

Comment: I want to send msg with french language, so I must to use a space characters like "é" "à". What can I do for it?

Comment: I understand that, and Twilio is able to support that. In order to fix your issue I need to know how you were sending the messages? What code were you using?

Comment: i don't use any code for sending messages, but i'm using zapier to send it for me, even when i try to send sms message with message service in twilio i get a same result

Comment: How did you try to send the sms with a message service in Twilio? Using the API explorer?